# Calling PL/SQL package code in a Java Program

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql, package

**I am trying to call a procedure defined with a `PL/SQL` package in a `Java` program.**

I am aware one can call stored procedures using `connection.prepareCall` in Jdbc. But there is very little information out there on how to call a procedure within a package.

I am at a stage in development where i am still considering what db framework to use. **Just wondering what are the pros and cons of using JDBC for PLSQL ?  For this usecase are there better alternatives to JDBC ?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Follow the simple steps below:

```
public static final String SOME_NAME = "{call   schema_name.org_name_pkg.return_something(?,?)}"; // Change the schema name,packagename,and procedure name.

// Simple JDBC Connection Pooling
// Here I am passing param companyId which is IN param to stored procedure which will return me some value.

Connection conn = null;
CallableStatement stmt = null;
ResultSet rset = null;

try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://hostname:port/dbname","username", "password");
        stmt = conn.prepareCall(SOME_NAME);//We have declared this at the very top
        stmt.setString(1, companyid);//Passing CompanyID here
        stmt.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.CURSOR);//Refcursor selects the row based upon query results provided in Package.
        stmt.execute();
        rset = (ResultSet) stmt.getObject(2);

        while (rset.next()) {
            String orgId=rset.getString("RPT_ORG_ID"); 
            // When using refcursor easy to get the value just by using Column name     
            String orgName=rset.getString("RPT_ORG_NAME");    
            // Some Logic based what do you want to do with the data returned back from query
} catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error extracting ", e);
} finally {
        DBUtils.cleanUp(conn, stmt, rset);
}

// Clean and close you connection
```

Comment: Thanks !! You seem to be using Apache's DbUtils. Is there a specific reason for using it over plain Jdbc.

Comment: Sorry, I copied from my own working project. Please Ignore that and I have updated the code. You need to add little code such as try and catch block and to clean and close connection. Hope you don't mind hard interpretation.

Comment: It's a very safe practice to use pl/sql over exposing sql directly in java code. Secondly, using pl/sql you don't have to make call to db multiple times which makes it quicker.

Comment: Seems like jdbc is a low level API , there are other high level API's like EJB , hibernate or JPA. Can i for instance use JPA or Hibernate to call PL/SQL procedures. I mean PL/SQL  being oracle's procedural language.

Comment: That's right there are various API's alternative to JDBC. Well it all depends upon your project architecture,framework and the requirements.I hope the above code snippet helps if you are using jdbc.

Comment: Please mark it as Answer if that was the expected answer to the above question,may help others.